# Include jQuery plugins with .getScript()?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm trying to load in the jQuery template plugin using jQuery.getScript, but even though it does the request and the file comes in correctly (replaced the url with a test JS and the javascript does get evaluated correctly), jQuery.tmpl is still undefined but if I run jQuery.tmpl in Chrome's console, it is a function.

Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
jQuery.getScript('http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js');
console.log(jQuery.tmpl); // returns undefined.
</script>
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wait until the script will be loaded.

```
jQuery.getScript('http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js',
    function(){
        console.log(jQuery.tmpl);
    }
);
```

Comment: At first was really surprised:)

Answer (score 2):

Wait until it loads. Try using:

```
jQuery.getScript('http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js', function() {
    console.log(jQuery.tmpl);
});
```

or to make it more readable, try using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js",
    dataType: "script",
    success: function() {
        console.log(jQuery.tmpl);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shuold use it in the callback(success handler) method of `getScript`

```
jQuery.getScript('http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js',
function(){
   console.log(jQuery.tmpl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the script is loading asynchronously, which means you need to wait for it to complete before you can use it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

The solution is to have the following:

```
$.getScript('.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js', function (data, textStatus) {
    //Use the script now
});
```

I'd recommend simply adding a reference to the script on the page if you're going to need it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap that in the callback as the next statement executes immediately, whereas script load may take some time.:

```
jQuery.getScript('http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js', function() {
   console.log(jQuery.tmpl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making the .ajax call sync, so that I could use it as part of my logic flow:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: script,
    async: false,
    dataType: "script",
    success: function() {
        console.log("Loaded "+script);   
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log("Failed to load "+script);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sync or async extension method to $.getScript: https://github.com/hudsonfoo/jquery-getscripts